# MVC 2 partial for edit/create return error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, partial-views

I got a question about MVC 2 and returning views for partials:

I got two views for creating and editing a user, the views both uses a partial so i can reuse the form fields.
UserPartial.ascx, EditUser.aspx, CreateUser.aspx

I got some logic in the controller post method (EditCreateUser) which finds out if its a new or existing user which is beeing submitted and this works fine.

The problem is when I try to return the edited user: return View(user). MVC complains about EditCreateUser file not existing. But thats only the method name, i want to return the object to the EditUser view which I am already on.

I could use RedirectToAction but i rather not because this problem would occur also if i want to return the same object when some errors has occured.

Any ideas on how to do this or some pointers in the right direction would be awesome.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within an action method named `EditCreateUser`, the statement `return View(user)` will by default look for a view with the same name as the action.  You need `return View("EditUser", user)`

Comment: Sorry for the late answer/comment.. This worked fine, thank you Clicktricity. The only problem is that the url will be EditCreateUser instead of EditUser/xx . But i guess thats fine, if someone doesn't have any idea of how to get around this :) ?